# Region_tlr_ssd doesn't preview on rviz (ImageViewerPlugin]) and no signal

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am trying to turn on the traffic light recognition using region_tlr_ssd but it doesn’t preview any result on rviz. I followed the ssdcaffe installation from [https://autoware.readthedocs.io/en/feature-documentation_rtd/DevelopersGuide/PackagesAPI/detection/region_tlr_ssd.html#] and installation and compilation done without any error.

I used the pretrained model that mentioned in the docs and save it in: Autoware/ros/src/computing/perception/detection/trafficlight_recognizer
and the model has loaded but I get the following message:

```
Ignoring source layer data
Ignoring source layer data_data_0_split
Ignoring source layer mbox_loss
```

The steps as follow:

1. initialized localization by run the TF, vehicle model from setup
2. run point cloud , vector map, and TF
3. launched velodyne from sensing and turn on the camera mindvision, launched the camera calibration.
4. launched ndt_matching, feat_proj, and region_tlr_ssd
5. opened the rviz  and added new panel  and chose tlr_superimpose topic.

System Specification

1. Ubuntu 16.4
2. Autoware 1.7
3. Cuda 9
4. ROS Kintenic

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322579/region_tlr_ssd-doesn%27t-preview-on-rviz-(imageviewerplugin%5D)-and-no-signal/) by [Eng-Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/41343/eng-mo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thiago de Borba](https://answers.ros.org/users/63996/thiago-de-borba/) on 2020-11-30**:
Hi,

Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I Mostly know the problem, the problem in the victor map. the vector map has to be very accurate otherwise it will never work at most cases, and the one which it used in the example is done by professional company and I am using a real car in real environment and don't have a ccurate vector map that includes all the road component.

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Eng-Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/41343/eng-mo/) with karma: 16 on 2019-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0